# Third party streaming library vs. home-grown

Tags: streaming, comet

I am aware of a number of third-party streaming component providers (Kaazing, Lightstreamer, WebSync), however, I was wondering what the general advantage of using a third-party provider is as opposed to a home-grown provider.

The scenario I am considering is where the user has a web display of around 100 entities, where there properties are updated at a rate of up to 3 updates per second. I could create a relatively simple JavaScript component that polls the server for updates 3x a second, dynamically updating the HTML UI based on the results received. With this relatively simple scenario, would there be any significant benefit to using a third party library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ColinE: The reason you are having trouble getting more answers is you have a bit of a loaded question. I think you have at least two questions:

1.) "Why buy 3rd party programming components?" *(broad and vague question) and*
2.) "Given my specific use case, should I buy a 3rd party real-time messaging component?" *(specific to your conditions and less about general knowledge)*

I'll take a crack at it though, trying to balance the broad knowledge for everyone who might read this to learn from and then addressing your specific use case. I work for the company that publishes the WebSync implementation of Comet/Bayeux so I have a lot of experience with this stuff. For the sake of equality I'll try to be very agnostic in my terminology, but its fair to assume that the feature/capabilities/benefits of real-time messaging that I list are based on my extensive experience with WebSync specifically. I don't know a lot about the Java and Apache implementations.

### Why buy 3rd party components?

For almost any third party programming component, there is an open source alternative available somewhere on the net. While its difficult to apply a one-size-fits-all evaluation of 3rd party components vs. open source, I would say that my experience has been that open-source stuff (ex: CodeProject articles) tend to have a short lifespan with no long term support. These open source style implementations are often built by one person trying to avoid the cost of a paid component to address one specific use case. For that reason they often implement only the most important features for *their* application.

When you purchase a third party component you are rarely purchasing just the basic idea. You are purchasing:

- a broader *feature rich* implementation tested and vetted by hundreds of customers
- with both a solid history and a plan for the future
- all wrapped with the promise of *excellent technical support*
- and *contracting availability* from experienced developers if you end up needing it

So the purchasing decision goes something like this: How many of my hours will it take to implement my own comet implementation? What is the value of that time at my charge-out rate? Is that amount less than the price of a 3rd party component?

Of course then you have to think about the risks and future: How reusable would my own implementation be on future projects? What risks am I taking on if the project's scope grows? Could my budgeted time allowance double or triple if the scope changes? How much time could I spend performance tuning for scalability or testing load balancing systems? What is my boss/client ads another platform to our project down the road?

Quite often if the project you are working on is a for-profit professional project, your own time savings and the support available with a third party component will be worth far in excess of the price paid for it. If your project is a not-for-profit, open-source, social start-up you will probably prefer to hold your pocket book a little more tightly and drum up some community support to fill the gaps.

### Differentiating Comet from Ajax Polling

Your question also eludes to fixed interval ajax polling as being an alternative to comet. I want to clarify the differences a little to help lead the final decision.

**Definitions**

One problem with the industry is people confusing Comet, Bayeux and Streaming. Comet originally referred specifically to *long polling* and has now become a bit of a generic term for real time message delivery over plain HTTP (protocol agnostic). Bayeux is a specification for how that data should look "over the wire" (a protocol). Streaming is the idea of sending something real-time over the internet. People often use them interchangeably implying one system with all three characteristics/capabilities. Some "comet" like systems, don't use the industry standard "[bayeux protocol](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html)". They are not one in the same, but you'll find "bayeux" is backed by a number of large industry players and specifies the way we talk to our servers for comet like applications. Bayeux is also what makes industry standard implementations play nice together (a good thing). I may myself even mix these terms up a bit, but at least now you know what I'm talking about when I say "Bayeux".

**Duplication of Data over the wire vs Initial State + Differential Updates**

With a fixed interval polling mechanism, you get exactly what it sounds like a fixed interval. With Bayeux the idea is to avoid duplication of data over the wire. If the data didn't change, why send it again? This saves you bandwidth costs and processing overhead on your server. Both very real financial costs to factor into your decision. On the other hand if the data does change 3 times per second comet will have no problem delivering that for you.

Taking that a step further, Bayeux allows for the concept of "**initial state + differential updates**". This means that when your javascript client starts up you subscribe to a channel which returns an initial state for your 100 entities (possibly a heavy data object) then the Comet mechanism continues delivering incremental differential updates. Example: entity 1 was just deleted, entity 7 was just edited, we just inserted another entity in the list, etc... those are differential updates to the initial state. You never send the full 100 entities collection (unless all 100 entities really did change in the last 1/3 second).

If you lose your connection (Wi-Fi drops out) the client will resubscribe and start over with a new initial state and then continue with the differential updates. This ensures you never "miss" updates. If you tried to do this with simple Ajax polling you would either duplicate data (eat bandwidth) or risk "missing" differential updates (unreliable).

With this arrangement you are always either equal or better in performance, bandwidth usage and overhead than an ajax long polling mechanism. In most cases you are considerably better with bandwidth usage.

**Bayeux Batching**

Bayeux provides a "channel system" to segment the data being delivered to clients. For example if you did a an AJAX polling thing, you'd end up with one big block of data that you need to parse (and generate server side). With a channel system you publish to channels like "/entityA", "/entityB" or even multilevel channels like "/entityA/fooMessages" and "/entityA/barMessages". The comet server will batch all published messages down to the client where the client can distribute the messages to the appropriate javascript handlers for each segment of data (each channel).

**Server Side Support**

While not available in all Comet/Bayeux implementations, I know that WebSync has an excellent server side eventing mechanism that allows you to "audit" all messages going in or out of your server. In these server-side events you could load new data, transform existing data, log diagnostic info, evaluate authentication status, call a 3rd party cross-domain API, etc.. A lot of power here for preparing/handling the data that you want to distribute to your clients.

### Should ColinE buy a 3rd party Comet Component?

Ok so now we have a broad kind of framework for evaluating the choice to go open-source or buy a commercial implementation. So lets step through the parameters you gave me in your question.

Each client needs 100 entities with 3 updates per second. So 300 individual JSON objects/messages flying around for each client. This is a lot of data to be pushing around. I'd say anything you can do to reduce duplicated data over the wire is going to benefit you significantly and so I would recommend a comet implementation with initial state + differential updates. Plus with so many entities being tracked, data segmentation with channels will really help you out with your coding and save you time.

**Option:** Poll server 3 times per second with AJAX.

Pros:

- Cheap and easy
- Light weight JavaScript

Cons:

- Updates 3 times per second regardless of the frequency the data actually changes (possible waste of bandwidth and processing overhead)
- You have to implement 100% of server side JSON generation and client side parsing of large (100 entity) JSON object. (No data segmentation through channels)
- You have to build all error handling logic. What happens if my Wi-Fi drops for 3 seconds? Will your requests stack up? Will you "miss" updates? How will you catch-up/restart the page? Or will you just keep sending ALL data 3 times per second?

**Option:** Purchase [feature-rich comet implementation](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/).

Pros:

- Minimizes bandwidth use vs. fixed interval polling (save money)
- Channels allow easy data segmentation (save time with implementation/parsing)
- Batching saves HTTP requests (better performance/lower bandwidth)
- Excellent error handling with reconnect logic, configurable timeouts (increased reliability)
- Server side support for working with events/messages/data (powerful and quick server side code)
- Proven reliability, scalability and client platform support
- Professional technical support, documentation, available contracting if you need help

Cons:

- Upfront licensing costs
- Feature Rich translates to larger JavaScript than simple AJAX polling

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I'd say the choice is up to you, I personnaly prefer to use my own library for this use. But here are the pros and cons of 3rd party vs home :

**Pros of the 3rd party libraries :**

- Could be more stable because they have bug reports from their users, you can't get this kind of support when you create your own library and use it only for yourself, you're the only *beta-tester*
- They have often more features than home libraries because they want to lure people into using their library and they must be highly-customizable to really appeal

**Cons of the 3rd party libraries :**

- They may have too much features to be lightweight and that's often to me the real problem, in fact many of them are quite slow because they're not specific to a problem but really general. And it becomes really a problem when you have to work fastly like 20 times a minute polling a server. And if your server doesn't reply fastly enough, which could be the case if you have many users polling at a time, it could become really awkward.
- You can't know the API of a 3rd-party library by heart because there are many libraries you use daily or weekly and you can't remember them whereas if you've written the code, you use your own conventions and you really know how it works behind the scene, so you're really in the best position to get the most out of the library.

So here are my thoughts about this  dilemma, I hope it'll be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping for some feedback from someone with experience in this technology, but appreciate your response anyhow.